How to handle some internal only endpoints in a micro-services architecture?
I have to get some sensitive data from like authentication microservice in other microservices, but i also do not want to expose that specific endpoint to the rest of the world, it should only be accessible to some of our micro-services. Can you tell me how should I do this? like should I create some specific users like m1, m2 and then check whether the endpoint is being called from one of those? or is there another way? I am using spring boot 3 with spring security.
I am thinking of solutions like making a separate user for each micro-service in DB and then while calling the micro-service's specific endpoint, checking if coming request is from one of those microservice or from outside world.

just add an interceptor in your application to check a signature header in your request, you can make the interceptor work only for specific endpoints:
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    // Get the signature from the request header
    String signature = request.getHeader("Signature");

    if (signature == null || !isValidSignature(signature, request)) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED); // Set HTTP 401 Unauthorized
        response.getWriter().write("Invalid Signature");
        return false; // Prevent further handling of the request
    }

    return true; // Proceed with the request
}

you can generate and validate the signature in multiple ways, you just need to make sure all your microservices will share the same secret

And adding on it, to do per service based authorization I should assign each service a different token and then store like roles for them in DB and then check? is there any better architecture than this?

In the first question, you asked just about confirming that the request is coming from internal service, but if you want a role-based authentication, you need to implement
authentication with JWT, this is better than checking the role and authorizations every time in the database in terms of performance also not all services need to connect to the same database, maybe you will have a service without any access to the database, JWT is always the best for authentication in microservice architecture
